# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index - shown in output, but test passes and returns right result

Tags: java, spring, junit, jdbctemplate, dbunit

faced this issue.
I'm using **spring** with **dbunit**, **jdbctemplate** and **c3p0**. I'm trying to create some tests for my dao layer.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-test-config.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
                     TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
                     DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@DatabaseSetup(value = "classpath:dbunit-testdata.xml", type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
public class NotesJdbcTemplateDaoTest {

private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotesJdbcTemplateDaoTest.class);

@Autowired
private NotesDao notesJdbcTemplateDao;

@Test
public void testReceive() throws Exception {

    Note note = notesJdbcTemplateDao.receive(2);

    Assert.assertNotNull(note);
    LOG.debug(note.toString());
}
```

This test passes well: in DB table is generated from dbunit dataset. I can get my test data from this table and print to log, but I also got exception message in logs.

```
2016-02-19 08:16:02 DEBUG SqlUtils:85 - Attempted to convert SQLException to SQLException. Leaving it alone. [SQLState: 99999; errorCode: 17003]
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1263)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getString(NewProxyResultSet.java:3316)
    at org.dbunit.util.SQLHelper.createColumn(SQLHelper.java:404)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseTableMetaData.getColumns(DatabaseTableMetaData.java:333)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData.getColumnIndex(AbstractTableMetaData.java:106)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractOperation.getOperationMetaData(AbstractOperation.java:89)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:143)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:66)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:186)
    ......
```

What can be the matter of it??
Also adding spring config and dataset

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${jdbc.testConnection}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="notesJdbcTemplateDao" class="com.sgleb.springrest.dao.impl.NotesJdbcTemplateDao"/>
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>

    <NOTES NOTE_ID="1" TOPIC="TOPIC 1" FULL_TEXT="Full text 1"/>
    <NOTES NOTE_ID="2" TOPIC="Topic two" FULL_TEXT="Fulltext 2"/>
    <NOTES NOTE_ID="3" TOPIC="topic 3three" FULL_TEXT="fulltext 3"/>
    <NOTES NOTE_ID="4" TOPIC="aaaaaaaaaaaa" FULL_TEXT="bcdefg12345"/>
    <NOTES NOTE_ID="5" TOPIC="note five" FULL_TEXT="note 5 full text"/>

</dataset>
```

and also piece of dao

```
@Repository("notesJdbcTemplateDao")
public class NotesJdbcTemplateDao implements NotesDao {

    private final String SQL_RECEIVE_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM NOTES WHERE NOTE_ID = ?";

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public Note receive(long id) {

        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        List<Note> result = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_RECEIVE_BY_ID, new Object[]{id}, new NotesRowMapper());

        if (result.size() != 0)
            return result.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

**Note 1**: if I'm trying to receive data from real DB, it works perfect (without dbunit)

**Note 2**: If I clean all lines inside **receive** test method - i.e. left it empty, exeption still occures in debug. So it seems that it's a problem with DbUnit

Comment: What is the value of the index?

Comment: @RomanC , 2, it's shown in the snippet. I have this item in dataset, DB, and getting it in the result. But also getting message about exception)